# Get correct current_page? when rendering a match in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I'm using `current_page?` to determine the current page to add an `active` to the appropriate navigation link.

When the login fails, it returns to `user_sessions#new`, but then `current_page?` doesn't recognize the `login_path` anymore, thus not adding the class `active` to the link.

I can't use `redirect_to` because I want to catch the errors in the controller.

How can I get `current_page?` to recognize the `user_sessions#new` as well?

Below is my code:

```
# routes.rb
# Following 2 lines ensure that the login url is maintained as "login" even there are errors after submitting the form
match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login, :via => :get
match 'login' => 'user_sessions#create', :as => :login, :via => :post

# user_sessions_controller.rb
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController  
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:success] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default profile_account_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

# _sub_nav.html.erb
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li<%= " class=active" if current_page?(login_path) %>>
    <a href="<%= login_path %>">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li<%= " class=active" if current_page?(signup_path) %>>
    <a href="<%= signup_path %>">Signup</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe changing

`<li<%= " class=active" if current_page?(login_path) %>>`

to

`<li<%= " class=active" if current_page?(:controller => 'user_session', :action => 'new') %>>`

should work.